# Using a bash script to connect to remote server , make and download mysql database copy

Tags: mysql, bash

I have seen the following example:

```
ssh server 'mysqldump -u root -p'mypassword' --single-transaction wordpress_database > wordpress_database.sql' && scp me@myserver.com:~/wordpress_database.sql /Users/me/Downloads/wordpress_database.sql && /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p'mylocalpassword' wordpress_database < /Users/me/Downloads/wordpress_database.sql
```

Will it work if I only have read only database credentials?

Thanks

Comment: @jini Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

This script does 3 things:

1) Connect to remote server does a dump, this implies you need ssh username/password if you only have db credentials it'll not be enough

```
 ssh server 'mysqldump -u root -p'mypassword' --single-transaction wordpress_database > wordpress_database.sql' &&
```

2) Downloads the file same as above you need ssh credentials

```
scp me@myserver.com:~/wordpress_database.sql /Users/me/Downloads/wordpress_database.sql
```

3) Injects it locally so you only need your local db username pwd

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p'mylocalpassword' wordpress_database < /Users/me/Downloads/wordpress_database.sql
```

Cheers.